# Embed current build time into humans.txt file with nextjs

Tags: next.js, vercel

Placing a humans.txt file into nextjs' /public folder works fine for a static file.

However I'd like to annotate the file with the date of the latest page build (when `next build` is called). So I created `pages/humans.txt.tsx` which renders a string that also contains the build time static date:

```
export default function Test({ buildTime }) {
  return `Hello ${buildTime}`
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
  return {
    props: {
      buildTime: new Date().toISOString()
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to customize `pages/_document.js` but even with everything stripped down (for testing) it still renders the doctype and one div with my text in it.

```
class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx: DocumentContext) {
    ctx.renderPage = (props) => {
      return {
        html: "text",
        head: null,
      }
    }
    // Run the parent `getInitialProps`, it now includes the custom `renderPage`
    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx)

    return initialProps
  }
  render() {
    return <Main/>
  }
}
```

Output:

`<!DOCTYPE html><div id="__next">text</div>`

Returning just string from my documents `render` instead of `<Main/>` still renders the doctype and also causes a warning, since `render` should return an `Element`.

So I am out of ideas and might resort to using a prebuild script in package.json `prebuild: sed ./pages/humans.txt...` to replace a marker in the file with the system date and pipe it to `public/humans.txt`.

Comment: An easy way to embed the current build time. [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70132444/how-to-show-the-app-version-and-last-updated-datetime-in-a-react-or-next-app/73082019#73082019)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an interesting runtime alternative:

#### Rewriting `/humans.txt` to `/api/humans`

You can use the following rule:

```js
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/humans.txt',
        destination: '/api/humans',
      },
    ]
  },
}
```

*Check the Rewrites docs [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites)*

#### Writing `/api/humans`

Now you can use any response in your API. However, make sure you are caching it:

```js
// /pages/api/humans.js
export default function handler(req, res) {
  res.setHeader('Cache-control', 's-maxage=6000, stale-while-revalidate=30')
  res.setHeader('Content-type', 'text/plain')
  res.status(200).end('example')
}
```

*Check the API routes docs [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction)*

Comment: Would it be possible to 404 the /api/humans route from public request? Meaning /api/humans should 404, while /humans.txt should work

Comment: Yep. Just include a new rewrites rule on `beforeFiles` to the 404 page.