# How to show the app version and last updated datetime in a React or Next app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I build my React/Next app using Github Actions. In the workflow, I have set up an automated system to determine the next release version. It creates a `.version` file containing the version and a `.last-updated` file containing the build date and time.

Now how do I use these files in my app and show the required information or is there a better way to do such a thing?

I want something like Notion:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. So I figured it out.

1. In `next.config.js`, add the following config:

```js
const fs = require("fs");

const version = fs.readFileSync("./.version", "utf8");
const lastUpdatedAt = fs.readFileSync("./.last-updated", "utf8");

module.exports = {
  ...
  env: {
    NEXT_PUBLIC_PACKAGE_VERSION: version,
    NEXT_PUBLIC_LAST_UPDATED_AT: lastUpdatedAt,
  },
};
```

> Note: For public environment variables, prefix them with `NEXT_PUBLIC_`.

2. Then in your JSX templates, use like this

```html
<p>Version: {process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PACKAGE_VERSION || "-"}</p>
<p>Last Updated At: {process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_LAST_UPDATED_AT || "-"}</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on [paulogdm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68968835/embed-current-build-time-into-humans-txt-file-with-nextjs/68988737#68988737) answear

Update `next.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/humans.txt",
        destination: "/api/humans",
      },
    ];
  },
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    modifiedDate: new Date().toISOString(),
  },
};
```

Anything accessible to both client and server-side code should be under `publicRuntimeConfig`

To get access to the runtime configs you need to use `getConfig`

```
import getConfig from "next/config";

async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  const { publicRuntimeConfig } = getConfig();

  const modifiedDate = new Date(publicRuntimeConfig.modifiedDate).toString();

  const content = `Last update: ${modifiedDate}`;

  res.setHeader("Cache-control", "s-maxage=6000, stale-while-revalidate=30");
  res.setHeader("Content-type", "text/plain");
  res.status(200).end(content);
}
```

The same would be true for your client side code.

Comment: I like this solution very much, but with Next.js 13.4.4 using the App router, I'm getting the error `TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'publicRuntimeConfig' of 'next_config__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default(...)(...)' as it is undefined.` from the line: `const { publicRuntimeConfig } = getConfig();
`